# React can't find Module

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, react-stepzilla

I'm trying to install a package called 'react-stepzilla'.
I've installed and saved this via NPM and made sure this is included in the .package-json file. All of the files are there too.

I've included the following at the top of my main Component...
    import StepZilla from 'react-stepzilla';

But all I get is this message...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M96Au.png

So I think it's looking in the wrong place for the module. How do I sort that out?

Comment: Try requiring it as `let StepZilla = require('react-stepzilla')`;

Comment: I tried that, but have got the same error. It's looking in the same folder as my current component :S

Comment: Try running `npm cache clean && npm install`.

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?  if `webpack` doesn't find a module in `node_modules` it will look in the current directory.  This is what's happening in your case which makes me wonder whether you're running `npm install` from the correct location.

Comment: It looks like this... https://infinit.io/_/3cjhTTz
In the left hand side you can see the folder under node_modules.
I've checked and I did install from the right place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There is no "dist" folder in the NPM package so the module can't be
>   used in a project.

[Current issue on Github](https://github.com/newbreedofgeek/react-stepzilla/issues/7)

Comment: Thanks for that, this was solved by doing 'npm install' in the module folder, and then 'npm build'. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for this...

There was some regression and the 'dist' folder got left out in a new build.

It will work now. 
https://github.com/newbreedofgeek/react-stepzilla/issues/7 is closed.

Make sure you run `npm update react-stepzilla` to get the latest version.

tnx,
newbreedofgeek (react-stepzilla author)